# PowerBI how do I expand a column holding integers into rows?

Tags: database, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I need to expand a large data set (around 90,000 rows) into even more rows, by splitting out each row into the number of rows for each page view.

I'm working in PowerBi and am relatively new to it - so please be explicit.

CURRENT TABLE:

```
--------------------------------------------------
|     Views     | Title        | Date            |
--------------------------------------------------
|     3         | Apples       | 12/12/20        |
--------------------------------------------------
```

WANTED SOLUTION:

```
--------------------------------------------------
|     Views     | Title        | Date            |
--------------------------------------------------
|     1         | Apples       | 12/12/20        |
-------------------------------------------------- 
|     1         | Apples       | 12/12/20        |
-------------------------------------------------- 
|     1         | Apples       | 12/12/20        |
```

Comment: Maybe it is your wording but normally you would NOT like to expand your dataset. If your request is to have a view with the same amount of rows as the count of your view, this is a differrent request. Please tell us a bit more what you need from the end users point of view, I believe we can than help you better.

Comment: What is you maximum number of values in view? like in your sample this is 3. Is there anything fixed about the number of split row? or that can be any number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow these following steps in **power query** to achieve your required output. From your sample and output data, I understand you wants to duplicate a row for the values exist in column "views". I am considering this below data as input-

[image]

So, according to Views column value, 1st row should be created thrice and the 2nd row for 5 times. **Note**: Change your Views column data type to Number

**Step-1:** Add a custom column to your table as shown below-

[image]

This will generate a list per row.

**Step-2:** Expand the list as shown below (right click on the New column)-

[image]

You have now data as below-

[image]

**Step-3:** Remove the new column "Custom" from your table.

**Step-4:** You can replace values from  your column Views to 1 if it is a requirement (shown in your sample output)

Finally you should have your required data now.